# Adding new handler to the web.config

Tags: iis, handler

I am developing a custom web application and try to change the default file extensions used to serve the webpages, I want to register new handler in the web.config so the user can request the pages with new extension: *.do

I am editing the web.config directly because I want to automate the procedure with powershell next.

.......

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could add below web.config try to use below config setting.

```
<handlers>
   <add name="SampleHandler" verb="*" 
      path="*.do" 
      type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

More details, you could refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/add

Comment: I am getting 500 error now, what about the type you mentioned ? I want to run the native asp.net that is used be default with any IIS ?